# excel text color depending on value

Tags: excel, text, format

I have a timeplan in Excel 2016.

If I type "o" in cell d2, I would like the text "off" to be shown in red. 
If I type "t" in the same sell I would like the to text "training" to be shown, but in green. And so on.

I think I can use user defined format - but I can't figure how.

Please advice.

Med venlig hilsen

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim D3 As Range
    Set D3 = Range("D3")
    If Intersect(Target, D3) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        With D3
            If .Value = "o" Then
                .Value = "off"
                .Font.Color = 255
            ElseIf .Value = "t" Then
                .Value = "training"
                .Font.Color = 5287936
            End If
        End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I will look into it. 
The reason I was thinking of customer format was, that I will use the facility all over the spreadsheet. 
If I use your macro I think I should use somethink like an event-trigger.
I am not sure, but I think my calendar will be placed between d3 and dd300, as I have multiple colleges and I plan for the next year or so.

Comment: @PeterGrandjean  This VBA macro can easily be modified to handle more than one cell.................could be a column..................could be part of a column.